# Maven test lifecycle in a multi-module project

Tags: maven, maven-3

Let's say we have a multi-module project parent, module1, module2 where module1 depends on module2.

If I run "mvn test" (not "mvn install"), will module2 sees the changes in module1?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will. Maven maintains cross-module classpath while compiling and testing.

Comment: Thanks! I had a "mvn clean test" which failed but "mvn clean install" passed, what could be the possible reasons? :)